# More answers please... - What is the most efficient way of doing this text search in SQL?

Tags: recursion, merge, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, common-table-expression

It's ugly out of necessity, but it still has to run in a decent time and I will show the two ways I've attempted to accomplish it. I believe a recursive CTE will finally solve it, but am having some grave difficulty implementing it.

Basically, I have a table in `db1` called `dis_det` with 3 fields that are important: `dis_id`, `dis_type`, and `dis_q_val`. `dis_q_val` is the text field to be searched for specific terms and phrases.

The search criterion are located in a table in `db2` called `tag_keywords`, also with 3 pertinent fields: `tag_id`, `keyword_id`, `keyword_name`. `keyword_name` is the list of text to search by and `tag_id` is a foreign key to a table with tagging information.

My end requirement is a list of `DISTINCT dis_id, tag_id`. I already know I can't just `FREETEXT` the whole thing because I get between 7-25,000 results per keyword while using `LIKE '%' + keyword_name + '%'` returns at most about 1500 results. It's not a huge test set (somewhere around 180,000 disclosure records by <1000 keywords), but the `LIKE` version ran out of memory at about 17 hours into the query, which is way too long for processing. Using `FREETEXT`, on the other hand, ran out of memory about 20 minutes in. I can get more memory, but I need accurate results in a timely fashion.

So my primary question is "Will a recursive CTE fix this?" and if so, "How do I implement it?". I'm also wanting to integrate a check for multiple words in the `keyword_name` so I can go with `LIKE` for multiple words and `FREETEXT` for single word values.

Now for some code:

```
--query using FREETEXT
DECLARE @i INT = 1, @keyword NVARCHAR(65)
DECLARE @results TABLE(dis_id BIGINT, tag_id INT)
WHILE @i < 909
BEGIN
    SET @keyword = (SELECT keyword_name FROM db2..tag_keywords WHERE keyword_id = @i)
    INSERT INTO @results
    SELECT DISTINCT dis_id
        , (SELECT tag_id FROM db2..tag_keywords WHERE keyword_id = @i)
    FROM db1..dis_det
    WHERE dis_type = 'reg' AND FREETEXT(dis_val, @keyword)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
--runs for about 45 minutes and runs out of memory with way too many results
```

.

```
--query using LIKE
DECLARE @i INT = 1, @keyword NVARCHAR(65)
DECLARE @results TABLE(dis_id BIGINT, tag_id INT)
WHILE @i < 909
BEGIN
    SET @keyword = (SELECT keyword_name FROM db2..tag_keywords WHERE keyword_id = @i)
    INSERT INTO @results
    SELECT DISTINCT dis_id
        , (SELECT tag_id FROM db2..tag_keywords WHERE keyword_id = @i)
    FROM db1..dis_det
    WHERE dis_type = 'reg' AND dis_val LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%'
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
--runs for about 17 hours and runs out of memory
```

I don't really know how to manipulate the examples of recursive CTEs to make them work with this. If you have an implementation that would work, I would greatly appreciate having it for use.

As near as I can figure, the anchor for the recursive CTE should look something like this:

```
SELECT d.dis_id
    , (SELECT tag_id FROM db2..tag_keywords WHERE tag_keyword_id = @j) AS tag_id
    , 1 AS @j
FROM db1..dis_det AS d
WHERE d.dis_type = 'reg' AND
    (d.dis_q_val LIKE '%' + (SELECT keyword_name FROM db2.tag_keywords WHERE tag_keyword_id = @j) + '%'
    AND (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',(SELECT keyword_name FROM db2.tag_keywords WHERE tag_keyword_id = @j))) > 0
    ) OR (FREETEXT(d.dis_q_val, (SELECT keyword_name FROM db2.tag_keywords WHERE tag_keyword_id = @j))
    AND (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',(SELECT keyword_name FROM db2.tag_keywords WHERE tag_keyword_id = @j))) = 0
    )
```

But that query gives errors, and I'm not sure how to write into it that @j increments.

Thanks again, sorry it took so long to post more information.

```
/*
 * -- Latest edit, still looking for a better solution: 02/27/2016 --
 */
```

I'm still looking for a solution that runs faster than my self-answer, which is just a working conglomeration of the above code. Depending on the state of the FREETEXT INDEX, it runs between 8 and 14 hours. This kind of thing is pretty much unacceptable in most situations. I'm hoping a recursion or merge technique will work more effectively for this situation, but am unsure how to implement such.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comment, I'm posting my idea about simply Joining the tables to perform the query.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1, @max INT = (SELECT MAX(tag_keyword_id) FROM db2..tag_keywords)
DECLARE @results TABLE(dis_id BIGINT, tag_id INT)
WHILE @i <= @max
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT details.dis_id, keyword.tag_id 
    FROM db2..tag_keywords keyword 
    JOIN db1..dis_det details 
        ON details.dis_type='reg' AND details.dis_q_val like '%' + keyword.keyword_name + '%' 
    GROUP BY details.dis_id, keyword.tag_id
    PRINT 'Iteration number: ' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(5)) + 'of: ' + CAST(@max AS NVARCHAR(5))
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
SELECT * FROM @results
ORDER BY dis_id, tag_id
```

Another idea that came on my mind, and which I'm actually doing from time to time, is some kind of pre-processing. Like when new keyword is added to the db2, some trigger on the keywords table would run the query and store the results in some table in desired format for you to only query it later when needed. This of course depends on conditions, but if db1 is growing fast and keywords are added not so often, it might bring significant performance gain.

Comment: I'm just going to give it to you. I expanded the code section to match the actual use. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Until someone suggests something better, I have come up with this blend of the above ideals for my inefficient solution:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1, @tag_id INT, @keyword NVARCHAR(65)
DECLARE @results TABLE(dis_id BIGINT, tag_id INT)
WHILE @i < 909
BEGIN
    SET @tag_id = (SELECT tag_id FROM db2..tag_keywords WHERE keyword_id = @i)
    SET @keyword = (SELECT keyword_name FROM db2..tag_keywords WHERE keyword_id = @i)
    IF(CHARINDEX(@keyword, ' ') >= 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @results
        SELECT DISTINCT dis_id, @tag_id
        FROM db1..dis_det
        WHERE dis_type = 'reg' AND dis_value LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%'
    END

    IF(CHARINDEX(@keyword, ' ') <0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @results
        SELECT DISTINCT dis_id, @tag_id
        FROM db1..dis_det
        WHERE dis_type = 'reg' AND FREETEXT(dis_value, @keyword)
    END
    PRINT 'Iteration number: ' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(3)) --to mark progress while watching it run
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
SELECT * FROM @results
ORDER BY dis_id, tag_id
```

Which runs for an approximate 8.5 hours. Obviously not optimal for something that may run once a month, but I'm sure the big guys across town can set it up for an over-the-weekend type of deal.

This will be the accepted answer until someone comes up with something that has a faster run time.

Thanks for taking a glance.

Comment: just to make sure, this 909 in while loop comes from the fact that you have  so many keywords in your database? should it be a parameter or do you rather want a generic solution whatever the entries count?

Comment: I've put some data into db to analyze the topic and I have one more question. Why won't you simply use JOIN between those two databases?
Something like 
`SELECT details.dis_id, keyword.tag_id
FROM db2..tag_keywords keyword
JOIN db1..dis_det details on details.dis_type='reg' and details.dis_q_val like '%' + keyword.keyword_name + '%'
GROUP BY details.dis_id, keyword.tag_id`

Comment: @JakubSzumiato At present there are 909 keywords, but it wouldn't be a bad idea to have it generically iterate through all existing keywords (as the number may increase at a later date). I never thought of using a `JOIN` condition to search. I will have to test it out to see if it actually works better. My guess is no since a `JOIN` will iterate through all 240k-ish ('reg') entries in the details, most of which are close to 4000 characters each. i found that using `LIKE` is more precise, but also much slower.

Comment: @JakubSzumiato The initial results (first messages from SQL Server) came in about 10 minutes earlier than with my patchwork query, so I have high hopes for yours being more effective. I suggest writing up an answer so you can gain credit for your better answer.

Comment: So how did you end up?

Comment: I'm just going to give it to you on the basis of initial performance. Someone decided to restart the server this morning before I had a chance to see the definitive results, and since tonight is my last night, I'm not going to wait for it to iterate all the way through again. If it's as fast (comparatively) as I think, it'll still be between 5 and 6 hours, but a good shave from the 9-15 hours I was experiencing.

Comment: I was more asking about the results, credits are not important for me at all. What about the preprocessing suggestion?